# Set Line under Line in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a problem with Notepad++ I cant find right feature for that.

Example:

```
45734734|1|2011|001|46734156|2|2012|002
```

I need this line with each other

Need:

```
45734734|1|2011|001 

46734156|2|2012|002
```

I try \n and \r but not working. Is there a regex way how I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand well your needs, but have a try with:

Find what: `^(\d+\|\d+\|\d+\|\d+)\|`
Replace with: `$1\n`

Comment: @user3338748: Sorry, I've made a mistake. see my edit. Have you checked `Regular Expression`?